# Find key name used to get value in Func<object, object>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using Razor, I am able to code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Code)
```

The result is:

```
<input id="Code" name="Code" type="hidden" value="A19H">
```

---

I created `Tags.cshtml` under `App_Code` folder:

```
@helper Span(string key)
{
    <span data-key="@key">@Model.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(Model, null)</span>
}
```

Which allows me to code:

```
@Tags.Span("Code")
```

The result is:

```
<span data-key="Code">A19H</span>
```

---

I tried to simulate the Razor method syntax:

```
@helper Span(Func<object, object> func)
{
    <span data-key="">@func(Model)</span>
}
```

So, I could code like:

```
@Tags.Span(x => x.Code)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the key name (in the above examples `"Code"`) from `Func<object, object>` to set the `data-key` attribute of the `span` node.

How can I get it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key is that your method needs to take an `Expression<Func<...>>`, that way you can determine what is actually being passed in. However, it all seems a little over-engineered and not too readable for your purpose.

Comment: use `Expression<Func...>`.

Comment: Especially when you already have `@Html.LabelFor(...)`

Comment: What are you trying to do here? A `<label>` is an accessibility element that is associated with a form control - clicking on it sets focus to the associated control but your not generating the necessary `for` attribute

Comment: I have a function `getModel` that finds elements with `name` attribute and create an object like `object[element-name] = element-value` for each match. This function is extended from jQuery, so I can use `$('.btn-whatever').closest('tr').getModel()`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke. I am using the `label` alone inside a `td` node, and I just want it to have a `name` attribute so I could find it with my js function.

Comment: Then it should just be a `<span>` or a `<div>` and you code can simply be `<span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)</span>` and it should be a `class` attribute not a `name` attribute (and if its in a `<td>` that suggest your duplicating it which would mean invalid html because of the `id` attribute (unless its really a `<th>` element in a heading)

Comment: And a `name` attribute is not a valid attribute for a `<label>`

Comment: @DavidG I double checked it, `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Code)` outputs `<label for="Code">Code</label>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Ok, I will change it to `span`, but how can I set the `name` attribute? I would want to code just `@Tags.Span(x => x.Code)` instead of `<span name="Code">@Model.Code</span>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138686/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-washington-guedes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x => x.Code` is an expression, so you would need to pass an expression (`Expression<Func<...>>`) however using a `@helper` is not appropriate for this.

Instead, you can create a `DisplayTemplate`. In the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder, create a partial view (say `_TableSpan.cshtml`

```
@model object
<span class="@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m)">@Model</span>
```

and in the main view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Code, "_TableSpan")
```

which will generate `<span class="Code">A19H<span>`

Alternatively, if you use this across multiple projects and/or your want more flexibility (for example to conditionally generate certain html based on parameters, then you can create a `HtmlHelper` extension method

```
public static class TableHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TableSpanFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        // Get the model metadata
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
        // Get the fully qualified name of the property
        string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.AddCssClass(propertyName); // or span.MergeAttribute("data-key", propertyName);
        span.InnerHtml = metadata.Model.ToString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(span.ToString());

        // To include the enclosing <td> element as well
        TagBuilder cell = new TagBuilder("td");
        cell.InnerHtml = span.ToString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(cell.ToString());
    }
}
```